# Changing the root directory Python and mod_wsgi

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I started using Mako templates engine on my localhost. However, everytime I want to select template, I need to enter full location of template (ex. **c:/Users/username/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/blog/scripts/templates/index.html'**). I want to change it, for example to enter just **'scripts/templates/index.html'** or similar each time.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mako's [TemplateLookup](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#using-templatelookup) class. For your example, using the sample in the documentation:

```
from mako.template import Template
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup

template_path = "c:/Users/username/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/blog"
mylookup = TemplateLookup(directories=[path])

def serve_template(templatename, **kwargs):
    templatename = "scripts/templates/index.html"
    mytemplate = mylookup.get_template(templatename)
    print mytemplate.render(**kwargs)
```